# How to calculate difference in altitude along lines using GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis

Using SRTM altitude information and OpenStreetmap roads, I want to calculate altitude differences (sum of meters uphill and downhill separated = two values) per road element.

What would be the fastest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dylan Beaudette has an article on [calculating raster profiles along a line segment](https://web.archive.org/web/20141220035731/http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/375) that may prove helpful. The basic approach is to convert the lines information into regularly spaced points with `v.to.points` ([docs](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.to.points.html)), and then extract the raster values at those locations using `v.drape` ([docs](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.drape.html)). This will get you the first step of the elevations along road segments, next you'd want to categorize the elevation pairs along a particular road. For example, given a raster `srtm_dem` and a road layer `osm_road` the analysis might look like this:

```
# convert line to points; dmax = distance between points
v.to.points -i -v -t in=osm_road out=osm_road_pts type=line dmax=90

# match resolution and extents of the DEM
g.region rast=srtm_dem

# extract raster values at our points
# use cubic convolution for interpolation between DEM locations
v.drape in=osm_road_pts out=osm_pts_srtm_elevs type=point \
  rast=srtm_dem method=cubic

v.out.ascii osm_pts_srtm_elevs > osm_pts_srtm_elevs.txt
```

From there, you could use a shell script, R, or Python to calculate the distance differences. In Python, that might look something like:

```
last = None
increase = 0
decrease = 0
with open('osm_pts_srtm_elevs.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        elev = float(line)
        if last:
            change = elev - last 
            if change > 0:
                increase += change
            else:
                decrease += change
        last = elev    
                   
print "total increase: %.2f" % increase       
print "total decrease: %.2f" % decrease
```

This is just an example for a single road, but could be scripted to run repeatedly across many roads.

Answer (score 1):

If QGIS is an option for you, the *Climb* Processing Plugin (plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Climb) will do exactly what you want. It can use a DEM to calculate the total climb (and total descent) for each line in an input dataset.

The documentation:

> The total climb and descent along the line geometries of the input
>   line layer are calculated using the Z values for the points making up
>   the lines. Z values can be provided by the line geometries or a DEM
>   (by using the Drape (set z-value from raster) algorithm to assign Z
>   values to the points that make up the lines). If a DEM is specified, Z
>   values will be taken from the DEM and not the line layer. The output
>   layer (OUTPUT) has two extra fields (climb and descent) that shall
>   contain the total climb and the total descent for each line geometry.
>   If these fields exist in the input layer the original fields will be
>   removed. The layer totals are returned in the TOTALCLIMB and
>   TOTALDESCENT output parameters.